# Access to the specified resource has been forbidden in simple Spring remote client

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying with spring remote client with security features,with out security things are working fine, but when I add DelegatingFilterProxy I am seeing the error 403 with message forbidden.

Here is my configuration

```
<bean id="provisioningService"
class="com.ravisha.spring.remote.httpinvoker.ProvisioningServiceImpl" />

<bean name="/provisioningService"
class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
<property name="service" ref="provisioningService" />
<property name="serviceInterface" value="com.ravisha.spring.remote.httpinvoker.ProvisioningService"/>
</bean>

<security:http>
        <security:http-basic/>
         <security:intercept-url pattern="/provisioningService" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') "/>    

 </security:http>  

      <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service id="uds">
                     <security:user name="test" password="test"
                               authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>   


</beans>
```

Comment: i tried spring logs in debug mode and found the error message "Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8081/SpringRemoteServer4.0.3/provisioningService"  for the ur i am requesting,

Answer (score 0):

CSRF protection is enabled in Spring Security by default from version 4. For HttpInvoker you don't need it and can disable it. I also suggest to explicit make security stateless.

```xml
<security:http create-session="stateless">
  <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
  <security:http-basic/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/provisioningService" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') "/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: Yeah I already did that. It's working. Also mainly it's required for non browser clients. Anyways thank you.